# How do I deploy to heroku from git when my API key is in a .gitignore file?

Tags: javascript, git, api, heroku, gitignore

I have my API key set to a variable in an apikey.js file, and I reference the variable in another javascript file where the API key is supposed to be.

I added apikey.js to .gitignore so that people wouldn't see it when I pushed it to my (public) github account.

However, when I try to deploy, the app doesn't work because of the .gitignore.

How can I continue to push up files omitting the API key to my repo on git while deploying on heroku?

Comment: Better use `config-vars` for this sort of tasks.[https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Answer (score 6):

use https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-config, and you can keep your secrets in a file called .env and ignore that in .gitignore

Install it with `heroku plugins:install git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-config.git`

You can run `heroku config:pull --overwrite --interactive` to generate an initial .env file that includes your service secrets, etc, and `heroku config:push` to save it, remotely.

I am assuming that you are using node, since your config file is javascript. To get the values in your .env file in node use `process.env`. For example to connect to your mongolab in mongoose:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI);
```

There is more about all this here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#local-setup

Comment: Does this answer your question?