# sendGrid not working when I deploy on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, sendgrid

I am having some problems between **heroku** and **sendgrid** once I deploy I can not send emails from my form, in localhost everything is working perfectly but in the live version I have a 400 bad request, does any one have some idea of what's going on?

I already tried this: in my config I set everything SENDGRID_API_KEY for example as shown here

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#provisioning-the-add-on

1)heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter

2) Setting SENDGRID_API_KEY and restarting ⬢ gammefive... done, v18

step by step but still is not working , there is something I don't see.
In local I see my email in my inbox everything is working 100% ok

Thank you so much

````
const router = express.Router();
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');



router.post('/api/contact', async (req, res) => {


    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

    const email = req.body.email;
    const name = req.body.name;
    const message = req.body.message;

    const msg = {
        to: process.env.GAMMEFIVE_EMAIL,
        from: email,
        subject: 'Email from gammefive',
        text: `name: ${name};
         email:${email}; message:${message}`
    };

    await sgMail
        .send(msg)
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).send(result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.status(400).send(error);
        });
});

module.exports = router; ```


**FRONT-END**

  sendData = async e => {

    const { name, email, message } = this.state;

    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      name,
      email,
      message
    };

      await axios
        .post("/api/contact", data)
        .then(res => {
          if (res.status === 200) {
            this.setState({
              alertMessage: ""
            });
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("important error", error);
        });

  };
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the relevant part of your config.

Comment: hi @Chris thank you I already sent some code but this is working perfectly once I push to heroku nothing works

Comment: @Chris I found the problem I  am going to write as answer because I Imagine  some people are having the same problem in the community. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I followed this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#provisioning-the-add-on
from the documentation and everything is working fine but the main problem is (let's say it in plain English) heroku is not recognising the .env file for obvious reasons: **GITIGNORE** file, so I found on stackoverflow another answer from here [How do I deploy to heroku from git when my API key is in a .gitignore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580313/how-do-i-deploy-to-heroku-from-git-when-my-api-key-is-in-a-gitignore-file)

I followed the procedure from that answer and the key is to install the package https://github.com/xavdid/heroku-config **DON'T INSTALL THE PACKAGE FROM THE ANSWER IS DEPRECATED** . Install `heroku plugins:install heroku-config` after installation you just have to run `$ heroku config:push` 
and you should start to send your emails.

I hope this is useful for someone facing the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should set **config vars** in heroku.

heroku config `set: {key}:{value}`

In your case

heroku config set: `SENDGRID_API_KEY:YOUR_API_KEY`

and **push** your changes.

You can also add you key value in you heroku project setting under Config Var section.

Hope it works!!!